# Creating a vector

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, vectorization

The output vector should look like :

```
a=[3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5]
```

What i have is:

```
pe=[1 5 9] and ne=[4 8 12] and co=[3 4 5]
```

pe describes the starting index and ne the ending index from each entry and co the value of this entry

I want do this without loop.
With Loop it should look like this:

```
  for i=1:3
     a(pe(i):ne(i))=co(i)
   end
```

Comment: the for i loop should be pe(i) ... etc, right? Also, how do you want to treat the case pe=[1 4 9] and ne=[6 8 12] and co=[3 4 5] ? use latest value?

Comment: yes ..my fault sorry ..it has to be a(pe(i):ne(i))=co(i).In the other case i just want to create with pe,ne and co the vector a from above.that means:first entry from pe is the first entry of co(1)=3 in a and first entry from pe is the last entry of co(1))=3 in a etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to create an array of indices into `co` first, using `cumsum`

```
idxList = zeros(1,max(ne)); %# create an array with zeros
idxList(pe) = 1;            %# mark the start of a new index
idxList = cumsum(idxList);  %# now, idxList has 1's where we should
                            %# place the first element of co, etc
out = co(idxList);          %# and we're done.
```

Comment: THANK YOU!Basically its so simple,but it did not came in my mind!